# Using Lucid for Simple Example

Tags: html, haskell, haskell-lucid

Given:

```
import Lucid
import Lucid.Base

mainPage :: Html ()
mainPage = div_ (p_ "hello")
```

I get the following compile-time error:

```
/Users/kevinmeredith/Workspace/my-project/src/Lib.hs:9:18: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘HtmlT Data.Functor.Identity.Identity ()’
                     with ‘[Char]’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘Term [Char] (HtmlT Data.Functor.Identity.Identity ())’
            arising from a use of ‘p_’
          instance ‘Term (HtmlT m a) (HtmlT m a)’ at <no location info>
    • In the first argument of ‘div_’, namely ‘(p_ "hello")’
      In the expression: div_ (p_ "hello")
      In an equation for ‘mainPage’: mainPage = div_ (p_ "hello")
```

How can I fix this compile-time error please?

Answer (score 3):

As is written in the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.9/docs/Lucid.html):

> **Intro**
>
> (..)
>
> For `GHCi`:
>
> ```
> :set -XOverloadedStrings -XExtendedDefaultRules@
> import Lucid
> ```
>
> In a module: `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, ExtendedDefaultRules #-}`
>
> (..)

So you need to turn on the `OverloadedStrings` and `ExtendedDefaultRules` extensions.

You can do this by **compiling with**:

```
ghc -XOverloadedStrings -XExtendedDefaultRules file.hs
```

But perhaps more convenient is to **turn the extensions on in the header of the file**:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

import Lucid
import Lucid.Base

mainPage :: Html ()
mainPage = div_ (p_ "hello")
```

Like the compiler says in the error message, `p_` and `div_` do *not* expect `String`s, but a `HtmlT Data.Functor.Identity.Identity ()` type (some sort of string). This type is however a member of the `IsString` typeclass, so it can be seen as "string-like" types, and has an implementation [[source code]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lucid-2.9.9/docs/src/Lucid-Base.html#line-200):

> ```
> instance (Monad m,a ~ ()) => IsString (HtmlT m a) where
>   fromString = toHtml
> ```

The reason this happens is because you can **add HTML characters**, in which case `(p_ "<foo>")` would look like: `<p><foo></p>`. But this is quite unsafe. By first processing it through `toHtml`, the result will be `<p>&lt;foo&gt;</p>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using literal strings, you can explicitly call the `fromString` method:

```
import Lucid
import Lucid.Base
import Data.String

v = "hello"

mainPage :: Html ()
mainPage = div_ (p_ $ fromString v)
```